How can I export the regression results of my fixed-effects Poisson regression using fepois from fixest in stargazer-like format?
I am running a couple of fixed-effects Poisson regressions in R using the fepois function from fixest. As far as I know, stargazer cannot be used in combination with regression output created by fixest. I have tried various alternatives, including modelsummary, kableExtra, and texreg. However, compared to the stargazer output, they do not deliver the same results I would need for an academic paper (asq style).
I am aware of posts such as Is there anyway to export feols model using stargazer in R?. However, I was hoping that in the meantime, some workaround emerged that helps to mimic stargazer output for R packages/functions that do not directly support it.
Thanks in advance for any help or advice on alternative templates to recreate the stargazer output as best as possible.
s. above
